# How to calculate Statistics for orders group by year in MYSQL?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, querydsl

Order table.

| id | created_date | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-01 | 100 |
| 2 | 2021-09-01 | 50 |
| 3 | 2020-09-01 | 50 |
| 4 | 2020-09-01 | 150 |
| 5 | 2019-09-01 | 100 |

Order details table:-

| id | order_id | product_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 1 | 30 |
| 4 | 3 | 10 |
| 5 | 3 | 20 |
| 6 | 4 | 30 |
| 7 | 5 | 20 |

So I need a MySQL query to get stats about order count and price and product quantity for each year.
The expected table

| year(created_date) | orders_count | product_quantity_in_orders | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 2 | 60 | 150 |
| 2020 | 2 | 60 | 150 |
| 2019 | 1 | 20 | 100 |

Comment: This needs in trivial JOIN, GROUP BY and SUM()...

Comment: Thanx @Akina.
I did that but my obstacles in quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this.

```
SELECT YEAR(o.created_date) year_created
     , COUNT(o.id) orders_count
     , SUM(t.product_quantity) product_quantity_in_orders
     , SUM(o.price) price 
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN (SELECT order_id
                 , SUM(product_quantity) product_quantity
            FROM order_details
            GROUP BY order_id) t
        ON o.id = t.order_id
GROUP BY YEAR(o.created_date)
```

Comment: Thanx @Rahul Biswas. It Works Perfect.
Can convert the query to Query DSL Spring?

Comment: Welcome @devloper152 for accepting my answer. I'm not familiar with dsl spring.

Comment: Nice solutions :)